# Changing a variable for each user

Tags: java, android, arraylist, updates

Quick question!

I have a arraylist made in my MainActivity.java, and everytime a person puts in a String in a certain place, that String is added into that arraylist. Now what my question is, does that arraylist update for every user using the app or does it change only for the user that put in the String?

If it's the first one, then how can I make it so that the arraylist updates for every user that has the app downloaded?

Comment: Are you using [firebase](https://firebase.google.com)? If not, that’s your answer.

Comment: Firebase Realtime database works for you.

Comment: From what i understand you save a string when your app is opened. That string is not sent anywhere right, like uploaded to a server maybe? If so, then your string only exists inside your app and the strings each user saves are never added together.

Comment: It seems you're right guys. Do you have any tutorials on firebase that you can send me so I can learn how to use it? Thanks.